# How to skip all files of one extension while svn chekout

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am trying to checkout an svn repository locally. Unfortunately there are .exe files in it. How can skip downloading thoses .exe files while I checkout. There are multiple folders and multiple .exe files and hence I cannot checkout one by one.

Answer (score 0):

SVN has no built-in way to do this. You could write a wrapper script to perform a sparse checkout, then get a listing of files from the repository, filter that list, then perform an update for each individual non-`exe` file. But that will be rather time-consuming and inconvenient.

Perhaps a better question is, why do you have compiled items in the repository in the first place?